# How to pipe vim clipboard through tmux?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux, clipboard

I noticed when using VIM through the terminal, I can easily copy a line of text to my system clipboard using the clipboard register like `V"+y` (that is, then paste that text to some other window other than my terminal using `Shift+Insert` or `Ctrl+v`.)

Now I noticed if I run VIM inside a tmux session, that doesn't work anymore. I know there is a tmux clipboard, but I'm never actually using that. Is there a way to get still get that yanked text into my system clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Clipboard):

1. Make sure set-clipboard is set in tmux:

> $ tmux show -s set-clipboard
> external

If it is not on or external, add this to .tmux.conf and restart tmux (use on rather than external before tmux 2.6):

> set -s set-clipboard external

2. Make sure Ms is set. Start tmux and run:

> $ tmux info|grep Ms
> 180: Ms: [missing]

If it is [missing], get the value of TERM outside tmux:

> $ echo $TERM
> rxvt-unicode-256color

Then add an appropriate terminal-features or terminal-overrides line to .tmux.conf and restart tmux. For tmux 3.2 or later:

> set -as terminal-features ',rxvt-unicode-256color:clipboard'

Or for older tmux versions:

> set -as terminal-overrides ',rxvt-unicode-256color:Ms=\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\007'

Then start tmux and check it has worked by running this inside tmux:

> $ tmux info|grep Ms:
> 180: Ms: (string) \033]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\a

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and your concise summary, works like a charm!

Comment: I'm now trying to find whether it is possible to get the same to work through an ssh connection, but it seems that this might be a lot fiddlier, do you have any experience with that?

Comment: It should be possible. I'd browse the SSH documentation or options if you're using something like PuTTY.

Comment: Oh it didn't occur to me that I'd have to check the SSH documentation itself, thank you!